# Where does Drupal render the content of the <head> tag?

Tags: theming

I'm calling [drupal_add_html_head()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_add_html_head/7) a few times to add meta data for facebook integration. To my surprise, this data is not rendered in the order I add it.

Where is this data actually rendered? I would like to examine the code so I can understand the logic behind it.

I'm aware there's [hook_html_head_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_html_head_alter/7) too, but without understand the render order, messing with the order of input data is not likely helpful.

Comment: Why you don't use [opengraph_meta](http://drupal.org/project/opengraph_meta) module? it will search for title, image and description and other required meta tags...

Answer (score 3):

[template_preprocess_html()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/template_process_html/7) gets the tags for the `<head>`, and adds them to the html.tpl.php template file as `$head`.

The template file looks like this:

```
..
<head profile="<?php print $grddl_profile; ?>">
  <?php print $head; ?>
  <title><?php print $head_title; ?></title>
..
```